# How do I load the contents of a file that resides in my app folder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, dropbox, dropbox-api

Using the `loadFile` selector and the `loadedFile` delegate selector, how do I read the contents of a file which is in my application's app folder on dropbox?

Are you supposed to `loadFile: intoPath:` and specify an absolute path on the disk (like a tmp folder?) from which you actually read the contents after the `loadedFile` delegate method is called?

Does the Dropbox IOS/OSX SDK automatically determine if the file is stored locally in the users' dropbox folder, and is at the current version, before fetching and downloading the file?

Am I missing something here? Or is this the intended implementation?

Sorry for the newbish question, it just doesn't seem like there's a ton of concrete documentation on how to actually use this method.

#### edit (for clarification)

When I say I'd like to load the contents of the file, I want to dump the file contents into an `NSString` object.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: we are supposed to use `loadFile: intoPath:` I think there is no other way to read the contents of the file..

Comment: Compare rev entries to a fresh metadata call to see if you need to pull the file again or use /delta for a list of instructions to get your local state to match Dropbox's remote state. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#delta

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSMutableArray *tempArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath error:Nil]];
 NSFileManager *fileManager =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSString path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 path=[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename with extension"];
```

Now you can use path variable for loading file.

Have a happy Coding.!!

Comment: this is much useful thnx :)